# Using Javascript to class manipulation in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it valid to use Javascript codes within a ReactJs project? I have something like this,

**JS**

```
myFunc(e) {
     let v = e.target.value

     if(v.length > 0) {
         e.target.parentNode.setAttribute('class', 'abc')
     }
     else {
         e.target.parentNode.setAttribute('class', 'xyz')
     }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input ref="xxx" onBlur={this.myFunc.bind(this)} name="xxx" className="xxx" type="text">
```

This method works as I wanted but not sure weather it's safe to use such codes in ReactJs or not. Please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

It works but generally this is not the [promoted](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html) way to go.
Since I don't know exactly what goes on in the rest of your code, below is my implementation based on your input above:

```
export default class BlurrableInput extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
             text = null
        };
    }
    handleInputBlur() {
        console.log('Hello from blur');
    }
    handleInputChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            text: event.target.value
        });
    }
    render() {
        let className = this.state.text !== null && this.state.text.length > 0 ? 'abc' : 'xyz';
        return(
            <input 
                 ref='xxx' 
                 onBlur={this.handleInputBlur} 
                 value={this.state.text} 
                 name='xxx' 
                 className={className} 
                 type='text' />
        );
    }
}
```

Ps. For the classname generation I can highly recommend [this](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) library.